# What causes the differences between a driver on disk and a driver mapped to memory?

Tags: windows, kernel, drivers, wdk

Hey,
Today I tried to do a binary diffing of NDIS.sys, and I noticed something weird.
I took a function, and began to diff it. The first 30 bytes were the same on the disk(using IDA) and on memory(using WinDbg). Then, something have changed. I saw something like "jmp _*imp*_XXXXX". the JMP bytes were the same, but the address was different.

My question is - what makes the difference? I think it has something to do with relocations. Altough the jump is to address in the same module, it's a long jump, which makes it relative to the module base address. If relocation occured, it needs to relocate this address too, altough its on the same module.

Am I right or totally wrong? :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, jump targets get re-written during relocation when a module is not loaded at it's preferred base address in memory. Actually, developers are advised to provide a non-default base address for their modules to avoid relocation cost, but many never do, so some modules will always get relocated and the loader has to re-write jump targets.

Comment: Note that for device drivers the preferred base address is entirely ignored

Comment: Yup, but - why the jump needed to get rebased? The jump destination lies in the same module..